# I'm trying to generate an SQL query that will add up flight times to show how many flight hours each crew member has accrued

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add the "char_hours_flown" from the first table, grouped by "emp_num" from the second table so I can see how many hours each crew member has accrued.

[2 Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do2X1.jpg)

Comment: It doesn't actually look like you are "trying". Where is your query? What part of the query do you have problems with?

Comment: And please don't post links to images. Edit your request and copy & paste the tables as text instead. See here why you should avoid images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2270762.

Answer (score 2):

Try using join

```
select emp_num, sum(char_hours_flown)
from tablename2 a inner join tablename1 b on a.char_trip=b.char_trip
group by emp_num
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be very straight forward based on what you have asked?

```
select sum(char_hours_flown)
       ,emp_num
from table
group by emp_num
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like following.

```
select sum(T1.CHAR_HOURS_FLOWN) sumoflownHours, T2.EMP_NUM
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.CHAR_TRIP=T2.CHAR_TRIP
GROUP BY T2.EMP_NUM
```

**Note**: Replace the name of TABLE1 and TABLE2 appropriately.